# Injection of resource dependencies failed in spring boot test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The following relevant signatures I've defined below. I'm running an integration test of mine and getting this failure:

#### Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consumerService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'CoolTransformer' available
```

I assume the context is being loaded as I target the config class. What could I be missing? I have a service annotation with a name on the service that is failing to load.. I've tried autowired as well with a qualifier.

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest(classes = ConsumerService.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyCoolConfig.class})
public class EventDecomposerIntegrationTest
```

```
@Service("CoolTransformer")
public class CoolTransformer extends BaseTransformer<GraphComponents> {
```

```
@Service
public class ConsumerService {

  @Resource(name = "CoolTransformer")
  private BaseTransformer coolTransformer;
```

```
@Configuration
public class MyCoolConfig {

  @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
  private String bootstrapServers;

  @Value("${spring.kafka.schema-registry}")
  private String schemaRegistry;

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

    return props;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>>
      kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
    return factory;
  }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing `MyCoolConfig` it's not clear you have anything that would create the `CoolTransformer` bean.  Does `MyCoolConfig` configure component scanning?

Comment: let me post the MyCoolConfig. I feel like I don't have that setup correctly.

Comment: @AlexWittig updated the op with config

Comment: ok, yeah, I don't think I see anything that would pick up the `CoolTransformer` bean.  Does it work with `@SpringBootTest(classes = {ConsumerService.class, CoolTransformer.class})` ?

Comment: Otherwise another option is to introduce a `@ComponentScan` annotation to search for beans and wire them up.

Comment: My tests are failing, so still debugging, but adding it in the classes array of the SpringBootTest annotation did get past this issue. Where do I add componentscan to? Seems like a lot of manual work to add each bean I need, but not super familiar with Spring

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230339/discussion-between-john-and-alex-wittig).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something needs to tell Spring where to find your `@Service` beans in order to wire them up.  You have told Spring how to find your `ConsumerService` bean via

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ConsumerService.class)
```

and you told Spring how to find `MyCoolConfig` via

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyCoolConfig.class})
```

But there is nothing telling Spring how to find `CoolTransformer`.

One way to accomplish this is with a `@ComponentScan` annotation.  That annotation typically goes on a `@Configuration` bean, so you might put it on `MyCoolConfig` with a package to scan, like so:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foo")
public class MyCoolConfig {
```

As long as `CoolTransformer` is somewhere under the `com.foo` package, Spring will find it and wire it up.

If `ConsumerService` is also under `com.foo`, it will also get scanned, so you don't need to specify it either.

Finally, since `MyCoolConfig` is now the entrypoint to all your other beans, you can simplify your integration test's annotations to:

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyCoolConfig.class)
public class EventDecomposerIntegrationTest
```